# Getting error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I am getting the error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference . I am trying to figure out the exact problem but unable to pinpoint the exact location. Was hoping someone could potentially help. I have 2 separate layouts with 2 separate adapters and list views. Been struggling on this for a while and would appreciate a solution.  Much Appreciated!

```
    public class viewContacts extends AppCompatActivity {

      private static final String TAG = viewContacts.class.getSimpleName();
      ListView listView_Android_Contacts;
      ListView viewContacts;
      View currentSelected;
      Cursor c;
      String contactName;
      CardView saveContacts;
      String phoneNumber;
      CheckBox cb;
      String currentContactName;
      ArrayList<String> selectedContacts;
      ArrayList<String> contacts;
      ArrayList<String> listMessages;
      LinearLayout linearMain;
      ListView currentContactsList;
      String contactEntry;
      public List<String> savedContacts;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_list);
        final ListView currentContactsList = findViewById(R.id.currentContactsList);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_contacts);
        saveContacts = findViewById(R.id.saveContacts);
        final ListView viewContacts = findViewById(R.id.contactsView);
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        get();
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        // check for permanent denial of permission
                        if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // navigate user to app settings
                        }
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, contacts
        );
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, selectedContacts);
        viewContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
        currentContactsList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        viewContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedFromList = (String) viewContacts.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(viewContacts.this, selectedFromList,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        saveContacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedContacts = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Integer> checkedIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                final SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = viewContacts.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.size(); i++){
                    final boolean isChecked = checkedItems.valueAt(i);
                    if (isChecked){
                        final int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);
                        String s = (String) viewContacts.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        selectedContacts.add(s);
                        checkedIDs.add(position);
                    }

                }
                startActivity(new Intent(viewContacts.this, contactsList.class));
            }
        });
    }

    public void get(){

        c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME );
        contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phoneNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            contacts.add( contactName + "\n" + phoneNumber);

            Log.d(TAG, "show contacts:");
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please attach the error log also...Even you pinpoint the error, others may see more useful information from that in order to help you.

Comment: Seeing the code
It seems that it could be on the line ```checkedItems.size()```
But you can figure it out from the error logs
It would say something like 
```Caused by: SomeClass.java:123```
The 123 is the line number that caused the error.

Comment: U r using two setContentView() in your code....remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The only place where you call `size()` in the code is here:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.size(); i++){
```

Assuming that that is where the exception is thrown, `checkedItems` must be `null`.

And therefore `viewContacts.getCheckedItemPositions()` must be returning `null`.

And that is as far as we can go with the information you have provided.

Over to you to do the rest of the diagnosis.

---

**UPDATE**

It appears that you are calling `setContentView` twice with different views.  That won't work.  An `Activity` has exactly one content view.

That probably explains NPE.  One of the two views won't be (cannot be) wired into the `Activity` and that's probably why it is returning the `null`.

You need to create a layout that contains / combines your two layouts.  Or maybe switch between the two layouts.  (Not sure ...)

Comment: I think you are right, the line that cause the error was currentContactsList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);  The reason I changed the view is because the list I want to use is from a different activity and I want to update the list from within my current activity. What do you suggest I do? Appreciate the response.